# Apache as a proxy

Tags: apache, proxy

How can i configure Apache as a proxy which will not redirect my browser as shown in 2nd diagram below but return the actual content of the server behind the proxy as shown in 1st diagram

i found loads of sources to do the redirecting but not the config of proxing (hide url-send content from proxy)

**i want following to happen**

```
         ->       -> 
browser     proxy     web server
         <-       <-
```

**not this**

```
browser -> proxy
        <-
   |^
   V|
server
```

Comment: i found this later                                          RewriteCond $1 !^(img|files|images|favicon.ico|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
ProxyRemote http://SomeNetwork/content http://proxyserver.com/content
```

I have not tried this for a request behind a firewall request.

Comment: this is not working, i want to hide the actual url, so when the proxy url requested from browser the proxy will fetch the real content from real server and send back to browser acting as the actual server

Comment: Hm, Ok. You can try this,
In httpd.conf or 000-default

ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost www.proxy.com

Redirect / http://www.google.com

A browser request of localhost redirect's to www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Set up "mod_proxy" for Apache, and then use flag "[p]" in your rewrite rules.

Visit http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html for more information